# How do I connect to a Firebird db from a Windows CE device?

Tags: vb.net, windows-ce, synchronization, firebird

Like the title says. I have a Firebird database on a PC and would like to connect to it from a Windows CE device. How do I do this? (If there is a way to connect through ODBC, I'd prefer that)

EDIT: I'm using VB.Net.

Comment: you can not use ODBC from WinCE device (both in CF and native apps)

Answer (score 2):

Older versions of the Firebird .NET provider have support for .NET Compact Edition (I believe support was removed in 4.x, or maybe in 3.x). You will need to compile from source yourself though.

Comment: As I mentioned all new projects SHOULD use multi-tiered architecture. Data Access Layer should be designed as desktop .NET app service (C# 4.0) and CF app should only access this service

Answer (score 0):

it all depends what language you want to use, odbc certainly can be used if you install the firebird client on the CE box